# Is there a way to view Session state/variables in ASP.NET WebForm

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am currently developing a webForm project. In my login form I store the user name in session variable

```
    Session["UserName"] = txtUser.Text;
```

My question is , Is there a way to view/hack this session variable in a browser?
Please share a working step by step. I'm thinking of the security of this web project. thanks for any help.

UPDATE :
Thanks for the answers. Based from your feedbacks, My webproject is secured Am I right? I'll vote for all the helpful answer/s. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Session state is kept server-side, which basically means that it can only be accessed from the server (this is true for all storage methods). So the answer to your question is no Session state cannot be accessed from a browser.

Answer (score 2):

Answer is no.
Session is a server object. In can be stored in memory or your web server (default), or somewhere else, depending on mode.

Read here

> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.aspx

Answer (score 2):

The only way to retrieve a session variable client side is when you store it in a javascript variable:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var UserName = '<%= Session("UserName") %>';
</script>
```

This only works, if you put this in your aspx file. Fired from a console window inside your browser this doesn't work, because your browser can serve just plain html and doesn't know about server side objects